# Flex Mobile 4.5 and 4.5.1 - how to Call a numeric Sofkeyboard on some text-inputs instead of normal

Tags: android, numeric, soft-keyboard, flex-mobile

Flex Mobile 4.5 and 4.5.1 - how to Call a numeric Sofkeyboard on some text-inputs instead of normal

without the solution of restrict, i want when i press a text input, i want to view a numeric buttons like 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0 like when i switched it to numeric

this problem is on Android, ios, blackberry

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is to build a custom component with that functionality and layout.

Comment: even if you add it it still the call for softkeybiard non controled

Comment: No - I mean build your own component and use it as a pop-up. Drop the softkeyboard entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Flex 4.6, there is an options softKeyboardType in which you can specify which mode you want the keyboard to appear in: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/SoftKeyboardType.html

Devgirl has a good blog with examples: http://devgirl.org/2011/11/29/flex-mobile-development-flex-4-6-cool-new-soft-keyboard-features-sample-w-source/